# Python Mechanize file upload keeps uploading 1kb files

Tags: python, file, upload, mechanize

This is how I initialize my mechanize browsers

```
# Browser
br = mechanize.Browser()
# Cookie Jar
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

# Browser options
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
```

After logging in and moving to upload page, I use this code to upload

It works, it's just the image it keeps uploading is always incomplete and is 1kb in size -.-

```
br.select_form(nr=0)
filepath = 'C:\Users\myusernamelol\Desktop\d6sEz.jpg'


br.form.add_file(open(filepath), 'text/plain', 'd6sEz.jpg', nr=0, name='file[]')


br.submit()
```

What's making mechanize NOT upload the full image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to open file in binary mode:

```
br.form.add_file(open(filepath, 'rb'), 'text/plain', 'd6sEz.jpg', nr=0, name='file[]')
```

And also, replace `text/plain` with `image/jpeg`